# iolanguage getSlot does not return expected object

Tags: iolanguage

Recently i started to learn iolanguage. When trying out the *"method"* message, i wrote:

```
Io> f := method(getSlot("f"))
==> method(
    getSlot("f")
)

Io> slotSummary
==>  Object_0x97f41a8:
  Lobby            = Object_0x97f41a8
  Protos           = Object_0x97f4090
  _                = nil
  exit             = method(...)
  f                = method(...)
  forward          = method(...)
  set_             = method(...)

Io> f
==> nil
```

But why calling to f will return *nil* instead of *"f"* itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [guide](http://iolanguage.org/scm/io/docs/IoGuide.html#Objects-Methods) `method()` introduces an Object to store locals and sets the local's `self` pointer to the target of the message.
Thus there is no slots from target but we can get them through `self`:

```
Io> f := method(self getSlot("f"))
==> method(
    self getSlot("f")
)
Io> f
==> method(
    self getSlot("f")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `g := block(getSlot("g"))`, which should do what you expect. Unfortunately, I can not explain why this is the case - sorry. I suppose it has to do with the fact that `block` and `method` set the `self` and `proto` pointer in different ways.

You can try the following within a `method` resp. `block` and compare the results:

```
call sender          #locals object of caller
call message         #message used to call this method/block
call activated       #the activated method/block
call slotContext     #context in which slot was found
call target          #current object
```